# How can I add a new field into a TypeScript\JavaScript object previously created?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am not so into **TypeScript** and **JavaScript** and I have the following problem:

In my code I created an object in this way:

```
var newEvent = {id: 5, title: event.event.title, start: event.event.start, end: event.event.end};
```

then after some calculation I calculate a new field named **uid** (basically the calculation is simply retrieve the UID after the insertion of the previous object into a **FireStore** database)

So now after that I obtained this **UID** value I want to dynamically add this new field to the previous object.

Can I do it in some way? If it is possible how can I implement this behavior?

Comment: `newEvent.uid = uid;`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
newEvent['newPropertyName'] = newValue;
```

Comment: Doing in this way the IDE give me the following error: "Property 'uid' does not exist on type '{ id: number; title: any; start: any; end: any; }'"

Comment: this can be the case when newEvent has type of "any"

Answer (score 0):

You can assign by using ., This means an Ojbect notation.

```
newEvent.UID = 123;
```

Not below

```
newEvent['UID'] = 123;
```

Because its an array accessing.